# Disable WiFi with CWWiFiClient

Tags: objective-c, macos, wifi, osx-yosemite

It appears that `CWInterface` is deprecated in 10.10 Yosemite, and it has been replaced with `CWWiFiClient`.

In `CWInterface` I would normally use the `setPower` method to disable WiFi, but I do not know of a similar method in `CWWiFiClient`.

Does anyone know how to disable WiFi with `CWWiFiClient`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get CWInterface instance like this:

```
let _en: CWInterface! = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface()
```

and now you can use the `setPower` method to disable WiFi again!

Answer (score -2):

According to Apple CWInterface and setPower is still current in 10.10, but has just been modified.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/frameworks/CoreWLAN.html